# A grey border just below my jQuery dialog after height changed

Tags: jquery, jquery-dialog

I have a jQuery UI dialog when I can delete a row on it like this:

[image]

When the row is deleted on my dialog UI, I see a kind of grey border just below my dialog like this:

[image]

If I move the mouse hover the page, this grey border disappear but I prefer to do it immediately by code.

I think I need to repaint or refresh the dialog.

Any idea how?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found a solution myself.

```
$('#modal-dialog').toggleClass("hovered");
```

Call this code after the height of the dialog changed.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the height once again when you delete the row of dialog content. Below is the script according to my understanding and use it accordingly.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var box = $("#example").dialog();

    $("row").click(function(){
       //existing stuff to delete row.

       box.dialog("option", "height", $("#example").height());

    });

});
```

Hope this will fix your problem

Comment: The height of my dialog is dynamic, I don't know his height, it depends on its content. Thanks anyway.

Comment: I am not giving any specific height in my example, I am getting the height via **$("#example").height()** and #example is the id of your dialog div, So it will come dynamically.

Comment: Right but your solution didn't suit me because it is possible that user remove lines several times, then the (new) height is different each times. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Yes so each time when user delete or append the row dialog would be adjusted its height accordingly.